# File size after File.WriteAllBytes finishes on mapped network drive

Tags: c#, file, operating-system, byte, hard-drive

I use [File.WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a file "somefile.txt". Does it mean that when File.WriteAllBytes returns from execution the bytes passed to File.WriteAllBytes are actually on the disk? For example I write X amount of bytes with File.WriteAllBytes("somefile.txt", bytes) and then check the size of the file on the disk if the size equals the bytes.length. If it equals I assume the file was completely written to disk.

Say the bytes size is 1.5GB and on the machine it takes a while to write such amount; the disk where the file is written is a mapped network drive. **Is it possible that File.WriteAllBytes returns from execution, but the OS is still writing bytes to the disk?**

Comment: I don't think so, as `File.WriteAllBytes` **closes** the file after writing the bytes

Comment: @Pikoh Does the method close() wait while the bytes passed are actually written to the disk?

Comment: I think close first copies all the data written to the buffer to disk, and after that releases all the resources. I don't believe it has a way to check it bytes are fisically written, but i think they are.

Comment: Anyway..why are you asking this? If you have a specific problem, i think you should ask about that problem

Comment: @Pikoh I am writing files to a mapped network drive. To show that the file is written completely I immediately after call to File.WriteAllBytes take DateTime.Now and put it to property WritingEnded. Here I **assume** that after File.WriteAllBytes returns the bytes are actually on the disk, i.e. WritingHasEnded. *I want to get rid of that assumption* :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's totally normal that the OS may (or may not) actually be still writing to the disk after finishing writing within your programming API. **That's literally not your concern, though.** If you ask for the size you'll get the expected and correct size that *you have written*, even if your OS utilized a write cache. Those processes are abstracted by the OS for you, so don't worry.

But as you mentioned network drives in your comment: This is not the case with network drives usually, though. Because the OS can't simply use a write cache and finish the write execution asynchronous. (Network may go down unexpected etc.)

Comment: Ty for the answer. It is a mapped network drive. In this case I have not to worry about incorrect size? :)

Comment: If your OS tells you it finished writing your data, without yielding any errors, you can expect it did so.

Comment: To be paranoid I just have to have use FileInfo and get file size after the control returns from execution of File.WriteAllBytes. :-F At least File.WriteAllBytes is synchronous (at least it says there http://stackoverflow.com/a/16746598/1737819 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/15467185/1737819 ) and it blocks execution for some time.