# libvideo get youtube video readable stream

Tags: c#, .net, download, youtube, video-library

I was wondering if there is a way to get the progress of a download for a youtube video using the libvideo for .net

I'm downloading using the following code:

```
var youtube = YouTube.Default;
var video = youtube.GetVideo(link);
string fileExt = video.Format.ToString();
if (!fileExt.StartsWith("."))
    fileExt = "." + fileExt;

if (!output.EndsWith(fileExt))
    output += fileExt;

File.WriteAllBytes(output, video.GetBytes());
```

Edit: To be more specific, is there a way to get a readable stream to a youtube video using libvideo?

Comment: This might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467135/how-to-learn-writeallbytes-progress

Answer (score 1):

the

```
video.Stream();
```

returns an unreaedable stream.
to get a readable stream use a VideoClient.

```
VideoClient videoClient = new VideoClient();
using (var Stream = videoClient.Stream(video))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what was going on!